# Launching gnome-terminal from vscode

Tags: gnome-terminal, visual-studio-code

Since updating to latest ubuntu and vscode, I can't launch `gnome-terminal` from vscode.

If I try launch `gnome-terminal` in vscode's terminal or via an extension then I get:

> Error creating terminal: Failed to get screen from object path /org/gnome/Terminal/screen/some-uuid-here

Ubuntu 19.04
GNOME Shell 3.32.1
GNOME Terminal 3.32.1
VSCode 1.34.0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just faced the same issue and now found a workarround. You can launch the terminal by unsetting the `GNOME_TERMINAL_SCREEN` environment variable.

To launch gnome-terminal from vscode:

`> GNOME_TERMINAL_SCREEN="" gnome-terminal`

Comment: Actually the latest vscode update seems to have fixed the issue, but your solution is good for those who haven't upgraded yet. Thanks!

Comment: lonix observation aside,  as of  1.54.3 on focal 20.04 this issue still exists and this solution works. an alias makes this easy.  `alias gterm="GNOME_TERMINAL_SCREEN='' gnome-terminal"`

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63947380/what-is-the-gnome-terminal-screen-environment-variable for some useful info about this environment variable.